# Animate of pseudo elements using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using `a:after`, it contains `right: Ypx`.

I want to use `animate` method in jQuery to move the element (`a:after`) from Ypx to Zpx, how can I do it?

For example:

```
[link-text][after]
[link-text]-- moving > --[after]
```

I know how to do it without animation, just doing `a:hover:after { right: Zpx }` but how with animation?

Comment: I'm not sure jquery can do this. You might, however, be able to use CSS3 animations to accomplish this (I believe), but it wouldn't be supported on non CSS3 browsers, of course, non CSS3 browsers don't generally support the `:after` pseudo tag...

Comment: @Shmiddty: Why not? `:after` isn't even new to CSS3.

Comment: @BoltClock You're right. It was added in CSS2. My mistake.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are trying to do is extremely hacky and I'd strongly recommend you to put make real elements instead of trying to animate pseudo-elements. However, for future reference: the only way of animating a pseudo-element is by inserting a `style` tag and changing the value in actual CSS, such as...

```
var styles = document.getElementById("pseudo-mover")
var distance = 100;

var move = function(){
    styles.innerHTML = ".box:after {left: " + distance + "px}";
    distance++;
    if (distance < 200) 
        setTimeout(move, 30);    
}

move()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/X7aTf/

This is vanilla js, but you could use the `step` callback in jquery's `animate` to hook in to jquery's easing and timing functions.

Comment: Ok, it's working of course but the motion isn't slick. I guess I should wait to some solutions in the future. Thank you.

Comment: No, don't to wait for future solutions (there will be none). You must change your code and use real elements instead of pseudo-elements.

Comment: The only thing I can do is <a href="#">Link <span></span></a> and I don't think it's semantic, what do you think?

Comment: `<a href="#">Link <span></span></a>` is orders of magnitudes better than trying to animate pseudo-elements.

Comment: Justify yourself! :P @Duopixel

Comment: @BillyMathews because animating elements with CSS transitions/animations is very straightforward, doing it on pseudo-elements is more processing intensive and requires a non-trivial amount of js. The only case where I can see is justified is when you absolutely can't touch the markup, otherwise make your pseudo-element a real element and animate that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS3 transitions to accomplish this, but sadly they are only supported (as far as I know) in FireFox 4+ right now.

http://jsfiddle.net/XT6qJ/1/

```
#foo:after{
    content:'!';
    display:inline-block;
    border:solid 1px #f00;
    padding:3px;
    width:25px;
    text-align:center;
    -webkit-transition:margin-left 1s;
    -moz-transition:margin-left 1s;    
    -ms-transition:margin-left 1s;
    -o-transition:margin-left 1s;    
    transition:margin-left 1s;    
}
#foo:hover:after{
    margin-left:100px;    
}
```

Comment: They're supported in plenty other browsers: http://caniuse.com/css-transitions ...otherwise, what would be the point of those prefixes in your code?

Comment: @tuff Yes, but not on the pseudo elements.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot afford myself to not support the other browsers, so this solution in CSS3 not gonna works for me. :-\ But thank you anyway.

Comment: @Luis Yeah, unfortunately, I don't think it's possible at this time.

Comment: @Luis - how about now? is it possible now? :)

Answer (score -4):

Use next() instead. [Here's how](http://jsfiddle.net/izaiasdotcom/ps2YG/10/) you can achieve exactly that.

Comment: -1 Completely missed the point of the question. This is CSS pseudo-elemts - the `:after` selector.

Comment: check out "[answer]"