# How to connect transition to ::before psuedo-element on hover?

Tags: html, css

I created a div that contains a background image and upon hovering an orange tint shows up over it. I used `::before` psuedo-element to accomplish this.

However, I want the hover to be smooth so I used a **transition**. It doesn't work, unfortunately. I've no idea why. I thought you guys could help.

```css
.img{
  color: white;
  height: 400px;
  background-image: url("https://watermark.lovepik.com/photo/20211203/large/lovepik-serious-businessman-picture_501473287.jpg");
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top 35% right 0;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  transition: all 5s;
}

.img:hover::before{
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(255, 88, 0, 0.7);
}
```

```html
<div class="img"></div>
<h4>Jon Doe</h4>
<p>Web Developer</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add transition to the `::before` pseudo-element. Also, add the `content` property before it goes into the hover state.

```css
.img::before {
  content: "";
  transition: all 5s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here:
[CSS3 Transition on pseudo element (::before) does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45225461/css3-transition-on-pseudo-element-before-does-not-work/45225634#45225634)

*The problem is that the pseudo-element doesn't exist when the container isn't being hovered*

So I've added the `.img::before` part and moved the transition from `.img` to the `.img:hover::before` and it's working.

```css
.img{
  color: white;
  height: 400px;
  background-image: url("https://watermark.lovepik.com/photo/20211203/large/lovepik-serious-businessman-picture_501473287.jpg");
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top 35% right 0;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

.img::before{
  content: "";
}

.img:hover::before{
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(255, 88, 0, 0.7);
  transition: all 5s;
}
```